# Minecraft - How to Horizontally Flip a Build?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit

So I have made a little build and then copied it. I am trying to find a way to horizontally flip it so that it is symmetrical to the other side, but I cannot do that with world edit.

Here is the build to give you an idea -
[image: image of build]

(the right side is a copy of the left side)

I've tried googling for other commands to use, but couldn't find a solution. Is there a command that could flip something vertically/horizontally with ease?

Comment: Tags are nice, but in the future you should better also mention the mods you're using in the description. Not everybody reads tags.

Comment: Btw, this also works in Vanilla now: Structure blocks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty dumb for not realising this, but I was messing around for a bit and  found out that the command is `//flip`
and you can do `//flip up` as well.

Comment: You wanna look in the direction you want to flip it